# Segal-Bargmann wave function for confined spaces (1D infinite potential well)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, phase-space

I'm trying to calculate the Segal-Bargmann wave function and the Husimi function for a particle in a 1-dimensional infinite potential well of width L (i.e. $V(x) = 0$ if $x \in (-L/2,L/2)$). In the Segal-Bargmann space, the Hamiltonian is:
$$
H(z)= \frac{p^{2}}{2m} = -\frac{1}{4m}\left[z^{2}+\hbar^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}-z\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial z}z\right] 
$$

The solution to the eigenvalue equation $H\psi^{SB} = E\psi^{SB}$ is:

$$
\psi^{SB}(z) = e^{\frac{z^{2}}{2\hbar}}[Ae^{\sqrt{2}ikz} + Be^{-\sqrt{2}ikz}], \quad A,B\in \mathbb{C}, \quad k= \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}
$$

Now, if I apply boundary conditions to the Schrödinger wave function, which can be accomplished by calculating the inverse Segal-Bargmann transform of the wave function $\psi^{SB}$:

$$
\psi^{Sch}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{C}} dz \ e^{\frac{1}{2\hbar}(-\overline{z}^{2}+2\sqrt{2}\overline{z}x-x^2)}\psi^{SB}(z)e^{-|z|^{2}}
$$

I obtain the following solution:

$$
\psi_{n}^{SB}(z) =
    \begin{cases}
    A\,cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}n\pi}{L}z\right)& \text{if n odd}\\
    A\,sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}n\pi}{L}z\right)& \text{if n even}
\end{cases}
$$

However, if I calculate the wave function $\psi^{SB}$ using the Segal-Bargmann transform from the usual infinite potential well Schrödinger wave function:

$$
\begin{cases}
\psi_{n}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)& \text{if n odd}\\
\psi_{n}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)& \text{if n even}
\end{cases}
$$

I get the following:

$$
\psi^{SB}(z) = \frac{1}{\pi\hbar}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dx\ e^{(-z^2+2\sqrt{2}xz-x^2)/2\hbar}\psi^{Sch}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\hbar L}}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-\hbar (n\pi)^{2}}{L^2}+\frac{z^2}{\hbar}\right)}\left[Re\left(e^{-\frac{\sqrt{2}in\pi z}{L}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}L^2-2\sqrt{2}i\hbar n\pi+4Lz}{4\sqrt{\hbar}L}\right)\right)+ Re\left(e^{-\frac{\sqrt{2}in\pi z}{L}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}L^2+2\sqrt{2}i\hbar n\pi-4Lz}{4\sqrt{\hbar}L}\right)\right)\right]
$$

if n is even, and a similar function if n is odd. As you can see, this expression differs with what I calculated using exclusively the Segal-Bargmann space (although it agrees with the result if $L \to \infty$). The problem obviously is the fact that the system is confined, i.e. the Schrödinger wave function is zero for every point except for a finite interval. When I apply the Segal-Bargmann transform which is very similar to a Gaussian filter, error function terms appear, which clearly cannot be obtained with the eigenvalue equation. So, how do I fix this? Do I have to change the eigenvalue equation? Can I modifiy the normalization condition somehow so that

$$
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dx\ (\psi^{Sch})^{*}(x)A^{Sch}(x)\psi^{Sch}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dxdp (\psi^{SB})^{*}(z)A^{SB}(z)\psi^{SB}(z)\, e^{-|z^2|}
$$

that is, every expected value of any observable A is he same for both wave functions, each calculated and normalized in their own space?